# Slideshow disappearing in IE & Div not responding to CSS style/positioning in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My site looks great in every browser but IE. On the home page, there is a div holding thumbnail images that will not respond to css positioning.
http://www.lucky-seed.com/

And on many of the other pages, my jquery slideshow completely disappears.
http://www.lucky-seed.com/web.html

I've done a good amount of reading but can't figure out these two issues. I am already creating a separate style sheet for IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the jQuery slideshow disappearing in IE, change your comment on [the page](http://www.lucky-seed.com/web.html) from this:

```
<!--end of description--!>
```

to this:

```
<!--end of description-->
```

After doing that, it's visible, but in the wrong position.

I will add to my answer after I figure the rest out. You've really asked more than one question here.

---

Amusingly, you have the same type of comment breakage on your home page:

```
<!--end of text--!>
```

You know what to do. Find all instances of these comments on all pages of your site, and get rid of the exclamation mark at the end.

They're severely confusing our good friend Internet Explorer.

Comment: Wow, OK. Thank you! Yes, you're right about the 2 questions. I'll be sure not to do that in the future.

Comment: Let me know when you have, and I'll sort the "div holding thumbnail images that will not respond to css positioning" problem, if it's still there.

Comment: Will do. Thank you X 100. -cara

Comment: No problem :) You certainly had the kind of problem that could drive someone insane looking for it.