# CSS Div positioning problem in IE

Tags: css, css-float, cross-browser

I have a JQ slideshow in a div on this page:
http://www.lucky-seed.com/web.html

and have a css sheet for IE with the following style:

```
.slideshow { height: 599px; width: 700px; 
max-width: 700px
margin-top: 00px;
margin-left: 295px;
float:left;
position: relative;
display: inline;}
```

Where am I going wrong? It looks great in everything but IE, but once in IE, I can't seem to move the position around no matter what I do.

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: oops. Nevermind, I see now that I'm missing a semi-colon after the max-width value.

Answer (score 1):

Hello fellow Pittsburgher :P

You've got so many different, conflicting styles going on there. While it's not a specific answer, might I suggest using a CSS framework like Blueprint ( http://www.blueprintcss.org/ ) to better manage your columns with greater simplicity and let it worry about IE compatibility. Rolling columns yourself is usually unnecessary these days.

Comment: Well, I'm flattered to get advice from one of my very favorite studio's in town. I've downloaded blueprint and will test it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `ieweb.css`, try changing the `margin-top` on `.slidenav` to `50px`, instead of `-20px`.

That moves the arrows to approximately the same place that they are in Firefox.

---

It might be an idea to scrap the IE specific stylesheets and do them again if need be. If you remember your [*question from yesterday*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938593/slideshow-disappearing-in-ie-div-not-responding-to-css-style-positioning-in-ie), you had a weird issue with comments. Those comments were causing parsing errors on your pages for IE, so I imagine a lot of the "fixes" in your IE stylesheets are no longer required now you've sorted those comments.

Comment: Thanks again, Thirtydot! The positioning seems to be the only little "fixes" I'm making on these ie sheets, but it sounds like if I use more solid column layouts, I can avoid this.